# Trace information not written to Zipkin

Tags: c#, .net-core, open-telemetry, zipkin

I am trying to use open telemetry to collect trace information

```
tracerProviderBuilder
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddZipkinExporter(o =>
    {
        o.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans");
    })
```

The writing to the console exporter works fine.

I have a docker container running Zipkin on localhost:9411, looks like it is working fine, except no data.

The client application is a .net core web api.

Edit:

I have created a test client that posts the json from the example in the Zipkin swagger documentation to the Zipkin server.

I get a HTTP 202 Accepted back. But still no items in list from the query search. But if I search by trace ID it shows up.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see data. Server has to be running for connection to complete..  Connection need to complete. Also see that connection completes using from cmd.exe >Netstat -a.  You have a virtual connection and and should see two connections 1) At Client IP address 2) At LocalHost. The client and local host has to be two different IP addresses like IP of machine and loopback 127.0.0.1.  Some machines have local host set to the loopback 127.0.0.1 and other machine use the IP address of machine. Using from cmd.exe >Ping localhost will tell how localhost is configured